# Django mixins that wrap as_view()

Tags: python, django, django-views, multiple-inheritance, mixins

In Django docs [Class based views - Mixins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/class-based-views/intro/#mixins-that-wrap-as-view) I found the following snippet regarding the use of mixins that wrap `as_view()` method to provide extra functionality:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

class LoginRequiredMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs)
        return login_required(view)

class MyView(LoginRequiredMixin, ...):
    # this is a generic view
...
```

In the above example the author wraps the standard `as_view()` method in a mixin so that each view that inherits from `LoginRequiredMixin` passes through the `login_required` decorator.

My question is this: For this line to work

```
view = super(LoginRequiredMixin, cls).as_view(**initkwargs),
```

shouldn't `MyView` inherit from `View` as well? Otherwise I believe that the call to super would fail for the reason that `object` doesn't have an `as_view()` method.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inherit from any generic class-based view. All generic views as defined by Django inherit from the base `View` class. The three dots (`...`) are a placeholder for any generic view class, they are not to be taken literal (and doing so would be a syntax error).

By the way, the most common way to decorate class-based views is to wrap the `dispatch` method in a decorator using the `method_decorator` from `django.utils.decorators`. Also check out [decorating class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views).

Comment: In the sample code it may not be clear enough due to the 3 dots but MyView seems to inherit ONLY from LoginRequiredMixin and not View. My assumption that super will fail is based on the fact that MyView may not inherit from View (i only see 3 dots) and as a result not have an as_view() method for super to call. So, regardless of the MRO, am i correct?

Comment: @Konos5 Ah sorry, I misread your question, I thought you were asking about the base classes of the `LoginRequiredMixin`. In my head I automatically replace `...` with the appropriate class :P But anyway, you are correct and I updated my answer. That's why it is a _view_ mixin.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I wanted to know! Thumbs up for the view inheritance explanation too!